# PHP can't get inner text from XML tag

Tags: php, xml

I have a small string in XML format:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('
    <imgs>
        <img mainfoto="true" date_changed="2019-04-07 23:27:50">
            https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_1.jpg
        </img>
        <img date_changed="2020-04-01 12:27:50">
            https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_2.jpg
        </img>
        <img date_changed="2020-04-04 12:27:50">
            https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_3.jpg
        </img>
        <img date_changed="2020-04-07 12:27:50">
            https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_4.jpg
        </img>
    </imgs>
');
```

I am trying to get the text(url) from between the `img` tags:

```
foreach($xml->img as $url){
    var_dump($url);
}
```

But this returns objects instead of a string(the actual url):

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["mainfoto"]=>
    string(4) "true"
    ["date_changed"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-07 23:27:50"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(52) "
https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_1.jpg
"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["date_changed"]=>
    string(19) "2020-04-01 12:27:50"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(52) "
https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_2.jpg
"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["date_changed"]=>
    string(19) "2020-04-04 12:27:50"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(52) "
https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_3.jpg
"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["date_changed"]=>
    string(19) "2020-04-07 12:27:50"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(52) "
https://example.com/data/i/pictures/size/333_4.jpg
"
}
```

I've also tried using `$url[0]` but i'm getting some empty objects.

How can i get just the `url` out as a string?

Comment: You just need to cast to `string` i.e. `(string)$url`

Comment: Thank you! I've spent a few hours on this so far and...now it works.

Comment: No worries - I went through the same thing myself when I started with SimpleXML. It's not what you expect to have to do...